# How to save user session in a variable in PHP to be referenced in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, usersession

Case:
User clicks on an image

- If it is a returning user (user session valid for 30 minutes) navigate to the link of the image
- If it is a new user show a pop-up div

I am now showing the pop-up div whenever the image is being clicked. Any advice on how to save the session and refer it as the variable in a JavaScript to perform a function like:

```
if {
    // user is log in.. do your task here..
} else {
    //user is not log in.. do your task here...
}
```

EDIT:

```
<script>
<? if(isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {
    echo "var $check=1";
} else {
    echo "var $check=0";
} ?>

function SetMood() {
    if($check==1) {
        // user is log in.. do your task here..
        alert('URL');
    } else {
        //user is not log in.. do your task here...
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is called for the image as:

```
<a id="register" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "SetMood();" data-fancybox-group="gallery">
    <img src="<cms:show my_image_thumb />" alt="" class="fade">
</a>
```

The above has no effect and now nothing opens `onClick`

Comment: i guess you can  write the javascript automaticly via php and insert the value of the session..

Comment: How exactly would I save the session in the JavaScript? Please see edit to the question

Comment: People have been using cookies to do this for a generation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't perform the conditional check in client-side code, perform it in server-side code.

Assuming you have JavaScript implementations of what you want to achieve, let's call them these respectively:

```
navigateToLink();
showPopUp();
```

Then you'd conditionally emit the code for one or the other depending on a server-side session check.  Something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['someValue'] == 'someKnownValue') {
?>
    navigateToLink();
<?php
} else {
?>
    showPopUp();
<?php
}
?>
```

The idea is that server-side code should determine what the user can or can not do.  Anything emitted to client-side code is entirely visible to (and modifiable by) the user.

Comment: How would I make a call to the php script in the `onClick` for the image? Since php only responds to get, post etc, will I be setting the value to true?

Comment: You can't. If you don't have the functions showPopup() and navigateToLink(), you still have to write them.

Comment: I already have the functions showPopup() and navigateToLink() but I need to make a call to the PHP on image click to show the correct function

Comment: @Sarah: If you want to invoke server-side logic without a page refresh then that would be an AJAX request.  You can have a server-side resource ("page" in PHP, most likely) which responds with data instead of markup, and the client-side code would consume that data.

Comment: I think you mean an ajax call, you want to call a php script using javascript?

Comment: @Sarah: Why do you need to invoke server-side code *after* the click event?  Isn't it known when the page loads whether or not the user can navigate to the link?

Comment: @David the login module which shows when the user session is not available calls an ajax function on hitting "login".In order to prevent the server-side code after the click event, should i save the session variable on the ajax call for login?where will I then check the user session?

Comment: @Sarah: I suspect you're over-engineering this.  It's not really clear what the order of operations is here, but it sounds like you're trying to perform authorization checks at the point of an action being requested (client side) instead of at the point of an action being handled (server side), which is where authorization checks belong.

Comment: @Pinki: Care to explain how?  It's a stated assumption that the JavaScript functions are already implemented elsewhere.  This is just conditionally emitting a single line of JavaScript within an existing JavaScript code block.

Comment: Oh boy, ok i think i need some better glasses :P my apologies. I feel so bad right now (and dumb) xD

Comment: @David so what should an approach be? Have to open a hyperlinked image - Need to see if it is a returning (registered/login) user or new user? If registered/login open link else show pop-up to login. Do i post it as another question? Can you advice?

Comment: @David, where and how will I call this php script, in the answer, on the `onClick` action?

Comment: @Sarah: I can think of two approaches. One is to display the link when the page loads if the user is logged in. Since you'd already know if the user is logged in, you'd know whether or not to show the link. Additionally, the link itself shouldn't be to the file but to a page which serves the file, so that page can also check authorization. Another approach would be to have an on-click action which makes an AJAX call to a page that returns whether or not the user is authorized. If they are, redirect them to that page which serves the file after internally checking authorization.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<script>
    var yourValue = '<?php echo $_SESSION['yourSessionValue'] ?>';
    if(yourValue == 'hello') {
        console.log('hide yo kids');
    } else {
        console.log('hide yo wife');
    }
</script>
```